# ngCordova local notification on iOS appears, but without sound

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, localnotification

I use the ngCordova local notification plugin in my Ionic app.

The notification appears immediately in the notification center on **iOS 9.3.3**, but there is no sound - neither if the app is open nor if the device is in standby.

I've tried many things and nearly read all questions on stackoverflow, but it still not work.

**Versions**

- ionic: 1.7.16
- cordova: 6.2.0

**Here is what i tried in various combinations with Ionic:**

- ionic platform remove android
- ionic platform remove ios
- ionic platform add ios
- ionic platform add android
- ionic hooks add
- ionic package build ios

I also checked if my app has permission in settings->notifications on my iOS device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i found a solution at Github. Now it works.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1031#issuecomment-232391644